# Minimum number of operations to reduce $n$ to $0$ using $+1, -1, /2$

Tags: algorithms, divisibility

Given a positive integer $n$, reduce $n$ to $0$ in the minimum number of steps possible using only $+1, -1, /2$. Note that when $n$ is odd, you can't divide by $2$.

I already proved that when $n$ is even (or eventually reduced to some even number), then the optimal choice is to divide by 2.

I am struggling with the part where $n$ is odd, and showing whether we should add or subtract. I know that either $n+1$ or $n - 1$ (not both!) will be divisible by 4, which means it will be divisible by 2 twice. So I think the proof comes down to proving whether we want the number to be divisible by 4 or not. If I was greedy, I'd say we do, but I'm not sure if that's optimal or not. How do I show this?

Suppose that $n+1$ is divisible by $4$. Since $n+1$ is even, and we know that when a value is even, it is optimal to divide by 2, we would go to $\frac{n+1}{2}$ and again to $\frac{n+1}{2*2}$. $n-1$ is also even, but divisible by $2$ only once, so we get to $\frac{n-1}{2}$, which is odd, so here, $\frac{n-1}{2}$ must either add 1 or subtract 1. Suppose that we add 1, at which point we'll divide by 2, and we get $\frac{n+1}{2}$. To get from $n$ to this point, it took 4 ops. But we saw previously that $n \rightarrow (n+1) \rightarrow \frac{(n+1)}{2} \rightarrow \frac{(n+1)}{2 * 2}$ took only 3 ops.
Now suppose at $\frac{n-1}{2}$, we subtract 1, at which point we'll divide, so we get $\frac{n - 3}{2 * 2}$, and this took 4 ops. It would also take us 4 ops to reach this value if we added $1$ to $n$ since we saw that it takes $3$ ops to get to $\frac{n+1}{2*2}$ and subtract $1$ gets us to $\frac{n - 3}{2 * 2}$. So here we see that if $n+1$ is divisible by $4$, then adding $1$ to $n$ will never be less optimal than subtracting from $n$.

Suppose that $n - 1$ is divisible by $4$. So this means our next 2 choices must be division by 2, and we get $\frac{n-1}{2*2}$. $n+1$ is not divisible by $4$, so we first get to $\frac{n+1}{2}$, which is odd, and at which point, we'll either add 1 or subtract 1. Suppose we add 1, and we get $\frac{n+3}{2}$, at which point we'll divide by 2 to get $\frac{n+3}{2*2}$. This took 4 ops. However from $n \rightarrow n - 1 \rightarrow \frac{n-1}{2} \rightarrow \frac{n-1}{2 * 2} \rightarrow \frac{n+3}{2 * 2} $, it also took 4 ops. Now suppose when we reach $\frac{n+1}{2}$, and we subtract $1$ to get $\frac{n - 1}{2}$, which is even so we divide by $2$ to get $\frac{n - 1}{2 * 2}$, which took 4 ops, but $n \rightarrow n - 1 \rightarrow \frac{n-1}{2} \rightarrow \frac{n-1}{2 * 2}$ only took 3 ops. So we see that if $n - 1$ is divisible by $4$, then subtracting $1$ from $n$ will never be less optimal than adding $1$ to $n$.

So we proved that when $n$ is odd, then we'll go with the option that gets us to a number divisible by $4$.

Is what I have done sufficient?

My next question is, is the number of operations proportional to $n$ or to $\log n$?

Comment: I think (not sure) the worst cases (relative to the size of the input $n$) might be from the sequence $1, 3, 5, 11, 21, 43, 85, ...$ (double then add/subtract $1$ alternately). Also, why go down to $0$ since you have to reach $1$ on the way? The extra step each time doesn't seem to accomplish anything. For that matter. I'd stop at $2$ since you have to reach it on the way to $1$ anyway !

Comment: Regardless of the exact optimal sequence, it’s obvious that the number of operations is proportional to $\log n$.  If you always pick $-1$ for odd it will be suboptimal but still only take $2 \log_2 n$ operations.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A061339

Comment: Is this from a programming contest?

Comment: @DanielV It's an algorithms problem, but I don't know if it was part of a contest.